# Google MAP Api - Storing GeoLocation

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-geocoding-api

Can I store the Geolocation (lat,long) for a place, business from Google Maps in a database ? 
The use case is that user should be able to select a location in the map and add comments to the location which I want to store in the database. So every time users searching for a location, I can pick up the comments from my local db.

Google terms says we should not store any information from the API, but if we want to create a location based system what API should we use?

This tutorial from google says about storing info into DB but that would violate the terms of google of not storing information. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

Thanks

Comment: Ironic how Google speaks of violating their terms when it comes to storing info.

Comment: Can you provide the document that says users should not store info from the API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en  check for 10.1.3 (b).. It says that you cannot store any content...

Comment: [Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) 10.1.3(b): "You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;..." The exception is rather vague, but it seems it's primarily intended to allow browser caching (and only browser caching).

Comment: I am trying to add comments to that particular location, to store that comments and I should have a relation to that place.. Now, after reading the terms and conditions I am not sure what is the solution. But I have seen many applications which store the address/geolocation of a place... example eatst.foodnetwork.ca/food-cart#addcart .. That is similar usage I am trying to do.

Comment: Based on the exceptions listed and your particular use case, you aren't allowed to do so. *For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.* -- which is what you're doing, correct?

Comment: On the other hand, if you were saving the Geocoded lat/lng coordinates to places to generate markers faster in the future, then that appears acceptable, based on *limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I Am Not A Lawyer, I didn't write or decide their terms of use and only Google and its legal jurisdiction are the final authorities on this. This answer argues from what is reasonable to infer.)

Of course you can do this. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to persist the location of anything and that would ruin the idea of this kind of application.

There are two parts to this: can you geocode and store a specific location and can you store a specific location to a business or other place that you've found by searching.

What Google's terms say are that you shouldn't use their services as an all-purpose geocoder. You are free to use the geocoder as long as you use it in conjunction with their maps.

From [the documentation on the Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12).

And from the [Maps API FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_exists):

> Please be aware of the usage limits that apply to geocoder requests, and note that use of the geocoder for any purpose other than obtaining locations that will be displayed using the Google Maps APIs is a violation of the Terms of Service. You may use the HTTP geocoder to geocode addresses outside of your Google Maps API application so that they may be cached and later displayed using one of the Google Maps APIs, but locations obtained using the Geocoding Web Service may not be used by any other application, distributed by other means, or resold.

With regards to storing the location of, say, a business, you have to be able to store the location at least temporarily so that you can implement your application. Otherwise, your every search query would have to go search for the location of every business to get a fresh, not-stored-in-your-database location back from Google. Since that can't possibly work, it's probably not their intention.

I don't think you'll be stepping over any lines until Google could argue that you're outright selling the information of a significant number of business locations in their database. You'd be far more likely to run up against their usage limits until then.

Comment: I am trying to add comments to that particular location, to store that comments and I should have a relation to that place.. Now, after reading the terms and conditions I am not sure what is the solution. But I have seen many applications which store the address/geolocation of a place... example http://eatst.foodnetwork.ca/food-cart#addcart .. That is similar usage I am trying to do.

Comment: Exactly. I can't point to the exact sentence in the terms of service that states that you can do this, but if you can't do that, that's 98% of all Google Maps API-powered sites and apps gone. The intent of the Terms isn't to enumerate all the things that should be possible but to try to define the things that they could disable your account for. They most certainly mean that you can't extract a load of data from them and resell it or vend it as your own, but they can't define that finely enough and they can't disable the means of doing so without botching the intended use.

Comment: For the final word on this, try to contact Google directly, be as specific as possible and ask them. And again, I wouldn't worry that much since nearly every other site using the API does just this.

Comment: -Terms has been worded so badly, likewise.. I am trying to create an app that users can search on the map and create an comment for it. I have store this in the db the relation for comments has to be geolocation since the id (can be changed according to google). Do you think this would be possible solution